# How to select a particular number in a list box and make the other list box to only display the numbers greater than the selected number in QlikView?

Tags: business-intelligence, dashboard, qlikview, dashboard-designer, qliksense

I have two list boxes: Box1 and Box2. Box1 has values 10,20,30,40 etc and Box2 has the same 10,20,30 etc.

After creating two separate list boxes for Box1 and Box2 respectively in the dashboard, how do I get to show only the values in Box2 which are greater than the selected value/values in Box1.

Example: When I click 20 in Box1, I want the values 30, 40 etc to be displayed or shown in box2 i.e., the values greater than 20 has to be displayed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way to do this would be to create a List Box but instead of setting it to use a normal field, set it to use an expression instead (select it in the "Field" drop down in the properties).

You could then use the following expression which should do the trick:

```
=aggr(if(F2 > max(F1),F2,if(GetSelectedCount(F1)<>0,null(),F2)),F2)
```

In the above, the first field is `F1` (i.e. Box1) and the second is `F2` (i.e. Box2).

An example of how it looks in practice is shown below (the third box on the right contains the expression), the first image shows what happens if some values are selected in `F1` - the list of values are filtered.

In the second image, a selection has been made in this new list box, and as you can see, it makes a selection against `F2` automatically.

[image: An example from QlikView when using the expression]
[image: An example from QlikView when using the expression and selecting values]

Comment: This is another great alternative to do it as well. Thank you

Comment: Also, this works better for multiple selections and if we do not want to utilize the trigger function. So I would go for this solution any day if I am not going to use triggers.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to achieve this.

- set "On select" trigger for Box1 field. The trigger will clear selected values on Box2 and select only the values that are greater than Box1 selected value
- in script - this highly depends on the dataset you have. The idea is to join Box1 and Box2 fields in separate table as many-to-many and then filter the values where Box2 > Box1. Using this approach is more clear to me and no triggers are needed but again it depends on your data.

Ive made a small app which shows the two approaches https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjGsOE_3VoOc29aYXVsanN3azA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Archid If this worked for you, please take the time to mark the answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Just did. Sorry that I missed it last time